# replace substring in list of strings in flask

Tags: python, string, mongodb, replace, pymongo

I am working on a project using flask and pymongo and I have a list of users where an instance of a user is like :

```py
user = {"Email":"user@gmail.com" , "Comments":["good" , "not very good " , "hated it "]}
```

I am trying to iterate through the comments of every user in my users collection and if I find the `string "good"` in any comment I want to replace it with `"bad"` . With my code below the string is replaced each time but not saved in my
users collection .

```py
user_list = users.find()
for usr in user_list:
    for comment in usr['Comments']:
        if "good" in comment:
            print("old comment here")
            print(comment)
            comment=comment.replace("good" ,"bad") #does not save the edited comment in the collection !
            print(comment) # the new comment is printed
```

I would appreciate your help with this simple task.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are changing the variable comment from your for loop not the value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the current code structure, you will have to keep track of where in user_list you are and at which comment. Then you can change the actual comment with the new one. One way of doing this is using `enumerate`

```
user_list = [{"Email":"user@gmail.com" , "Comments":["good" , "not very good " , "hated it "]}]
for idxu, usr in enumerate(user_list):
    for idxc, comment in enumerate(usr['Comments']):
        if "good" in comment:
            print("old comment here")
            print(comment)
            user_list[idxu]['Comments'][idxc] = comment.replace("good" ,"bad") #does not save the edited comment in the collection !
            print(comment) # the new comment is printed

print(user_list)

>>> [{'Email': 'user@gmail.com', 'Comments': ['bad', 'not very bad ', 'hated it ']}]
```

If you want to store the changes in mongodb you'll ofcourse have to save the changes to the user objects.

Comment: I have user_list = users.find()

Comment: I get in user_list[idxu]['Comments'][idxc] = comment.replace("good" ,"bad") 
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the user comments, which isn't done in your code.

```py
for usr in user_list:
    usr["Comments"] = [i.replace("good", "bad") for i in usr["Comments"]]
```

Eg.

```py
user = {"Email":"user@gmail.com" , "Comments":["good" , "not very good " , "hated it "]}

user_list = [user]
print (user_list)

for usr in user_list:
    usr["Comments"] = [i.replace("good", "bad") for i in usr["Comments"]]

print (user_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'Email': 'user@gmail.com', 'Comments': ['good', 'not very good ', 'hated it ']}]
[{'Email': 'user@gmail.com', 'Comments': ['bad', 'not very bad ', 'hated it ']}]
```

Comment: It didn't work . Maybe there is something wrong in the code

Comment: I have user_list  = users.find() not only one user

Comment: You just have to replace like 3 on my code to whatever list of users that you might like :D

Comment: I got 'usr' does not support item assignment in usr['Comments'] . I did also                         user_list = [users.find()]